# Access multiple elements by dynamic id and class inside a loop (multidimensional array?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the confusing title.

I'm working on this code: https://jsfiddle.net/8ers54s9/13/

It creates a simple text area and compares it to a predefined array for common words in a string. If any match, it changes the button color and shows some rows of a table. Try inputting "cat" and/or "blue".

That code is fully functional, however I will need to create up to 20 new arrays / buttons to check (there are two now - colors and animals - and I will add forms, emotions, names, cities, etc). As the code is very poorly optimized, I would need to actually copy-paste all the code for each new array type. I would like to know if there is a way to create most of the work inside for loops.

I thought about creating a multidimensional array that works as a "settings" base, like:

```
var mainSettings = [
  ["Color", "colorArray", "colorGroup", "colorbutton"],
  ["Animal", "animalArray", "animalGroup", "animalbutton"]
];
```

And just call it by mainSettings[i][0], mainSettings[i][1] etc...

However I can't implement this idea (multiple undefined errors) or think about any other. What would be the best approach?

This part would be the most important one to avoid replicating:

```
if (manual.Color == true) {
    $('#colorbutton').removeClass().addClass('button blue');
    $('.colorGroup').show();
    $('#header').show();
}
if (manual.Color == false) {
    if (test.Color == true) {
        $('#colorbutton').removeClass().addClass('button green');
        $('.colorGroup').show();
        $('#header').show();
    }
    if (test.Color == false) $('#colorbutton').removeClass().addClass('button black');
}

if (manual.Animal == true) {
    $('#animalbutton').removeClass().addClass('button blue');
    $('.animalGroup').show();
    $('#header').show();
}
if (manual.Animal == false) {
    if (test.Animal == true) {
        $('#animalbutton').removeClass().addClass('button green');
        $('.animalGroup').show();
        $('#header').show();
    }
    if (test.Animal == false) $('#animalbutton').removeClass().addClass('button black');
}
```

You can see it's just repeating code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it would be a good exercise, here is a really simple prototype I made:

try inputting 'green' or 'cat'

```js
/**
  @typedef KeywordButton
  @type {object}
  @property {string} id - the button ID, must be unique
  @property {string[]} keywords - a string array of keywords
  @property {string} title - The button title
  @property {string} color - The button border color
 */

function KeywordWidget(inputSelector, buttonsSelector) {
  this.$input = $(inputSelector);
  this.$buttons = $(buttonsSelector);
  var _keywordButtons = [];
  var widget = this;
  
  // register input event
  this.$input.on('input', function() {
    var text = widget.$input.val();
    _keywordButtons.forEach(function(keywordButton) {
      var keywords = keywordButton.keywords;
      var button = widget.$buttons.find('#' + keywordButton.id);
      var keywordExixts = keywords.some(function(v) {
        return text.indexOf(v) > -1;
      });
      if (keywordExixts) button.css('border-color', keywordButton.color);
      else button.css('border-color', 'black');
    });
  });

  /**
   * function to add new button
   * @param {KeywordButton} keywordButton - a keyword button config object
   */
  this.add = function(keywordButton) {
    if (_idExists(keywordButton.id)) throw new Error("id: " + keywordButton.id + " already exists");
    _keywordButtons.push(keywordButton);
    var $button = $('<button type="button" class="button">' + keywordButton.title + '</button>');
    $button.attr("id", keywordButton.id);
    this.$buttons.append($button);
  }

  // helper to check if id exists
  function _idExists(id) {
    return _keywordButtons.some(function(button) {
      button.id === id
    });
  }
}

var w = new KeywordWidget("#input", "#buttons");
// add color button
w.add({
  id: "color",
  title: "Color",
  keywords: ["green", "blue"],
  color: "red"
});
// add animal button
w.add({
  id: "animal",
  title: "Animal",
  keywords: ["dog", "cat"],
  color: "blue"
});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea id="input" placeholder="Test one" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
```

Comment: Very nice implementation. Thanks a lot. It will, however, take me quite a few reads to understand it. A couple of differences though: button color is not defined by the keywordwidget (colors, animals, etc), it's defined by the match status. If the arrays match (text and keywords), it's green, if they do not match but you click the button, it's blue, else black. Also, based on the matching status (if green/blue or black), I will need to add/show some rows in the table bellow.

Comment: I usually add more documentation, but don't have much time today. I thought it might be helpful for you to build on this code and  implement the table requirement :)

Comment: Nope. Don't have the knowledge to work with your solution, specially cause I'll still need to create the parts I couldn't do in the first place (the button on click function and the bottom if clauses - manual button click and text check).